# Url shortener service - Convert multiple urls with one request

Tags: android, google-api, url-shortener, google-url-shortener

Im currently using [Google Url shortener API](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/) from my android app. The problem with this service is the fact that it only gets one url per request, Whice forces me to make multiple network accesses. Is there any service/way to convert multiple urls with once request ?

Thanks.